# Google Sheets: Mailto Script Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this script isn't sending out my emails. I'm almost positive the script is correct and there is an issue with my settings on my Google Sheet. But was wondering if anyone could see any issues or help me find out why this script wont run.

```js
function sendMail(e) {
  
  var cellvalue = e.value;
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var PRSR = sheet.getRange("B"+e.range.getRow()).getValue();
  
  var aValue = sheet.getRange("A"+e.range.getRow()).getValue();
  var cValue = sheet.getRange("C"+e.range.getRow()).getValue();
  var dValue = sheet.getRange("D"+e.range.getRow()).getValue();
  
  switch(PRSR){
    case "SP":
      recipients = "admin@myutahmortgage.com";
      break;
    case "TD":
      recipients = "admin@myutahmortgage.com";
      break;
    case "BM":
      recipients = "admin@myutahmortgage.com";
      break;
    default:
      recipients = "admin@myutahmortgage.com";
      break;
  }

  var message = '';
  if(cellvalue.toUpperCase() === 'NO' && parseInt(e.range.getColumn()) == 6){ 
    
    message = 'Cell ' + cell + ' in Sheet ' + sheetName + ' was changed to NO.';
    message = message + " "+ aValue + " " + cValue + " "+dValue;
    
    var subject = 'Cell Changed to NO in Inspection Checklist';
    var body = message + '  Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script worked fine for me.  I set it up in a spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fKGBOyvWG0qkN5ldCM4WbMuP9gp31NCXjQLQvVaaNTE/edit?usp=sharing

I went to menu item 'Current project's triggers' and set a trigger to run

- sendMail | From spreadsheet | On edit

[image: Google Apps Script Current project's trigger set sendMail function, From spreadsheet, On edit]

I added data to the spreadsheet which satisfy your script statements across A:F

[image]

When I change an OK to NO, it satisfies your 'if' tests in the script line below, so sends the email.

if(cellvalue.toUpperCase() === 'NO' && parseInt(e.range.getColumn()) == 6){